# How to call a javascript function in a rails form?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a rails form that looks like this :

```
= form_for :location, :url=>'/welcome' do |f|
  = f.text_field '', placeholder: 'Enter your zip code', id:'input_id'
  = f.button "Continue", class: 'button-test'
```

So when the button continue is clicked upon , rails get the controller and execute the method `/welcome`

so what i am trying to do is to actually execute a simple javascript function like :

```
function wawa() {
 alert('it works')
};
```

when the button continue is cliked instead of rails getting to execute the method `/welcome`.

How can I approach this problem using Javascript only and no library ?

Comment: You need to add a JavaScript listener to the submit element that will call preventDefault() on that element.  That will give you a chance to modify the DOM before the form is submitted.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `submit()` function of `jquery`.

```
= form_for :location, :url=>'/welcome', html: {id: "id_form_location"} do |f|
 = f.text_field '', placeholder: 'Enter your zip code', id:'input_id'
 = f.button "Continue", class: 'button-test'
```

In javascript file:

```
$("#id_form_location").submit(function(event) {
  alert('it works');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some JavaScript [On submit Listener](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onsubmit_addeventlistener) I suppose you need it before form is submit. If you want only on click then have a look at [on click Listener](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onclick_addeventlistener) also have a look at [event prevent](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp) as it will help you to prevent from default behaviour of button.

Try this code

```
<%=  form_for :location, :url=>'/welcome' do |f| %>
  <%=  f.text_field '', placeholder: 'Enter your zip code', id:'input_id' %>
  <%=  f.button "Continue", class: 'button-test', id: 'demo' %>
 <% end %>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("demo").addEventListener("click", function(event){
        event.preventDefault()
        alert('Hello')
    });
</script>
```

Comment: okay so how do I implement that ? Im kinda new in rails and this is my first serious project

Comment: Are you using jquery?

Comment: okk than I suggest you to have a look at https://sleekd.com/tutorials/jquery-validation-in-ruby-on-rails/ It implement validation on submit. Just replace code of jquery with javascript mentioned in answer.